# logstash output config file

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash

In the logstash kafka configuration file, if there is a connection failure in the output, it will block. How to ensure that one connection fails and the remaining connections run normally
[image]

```
input{
stdin{}
}
output {
kafka {
bootstrap_servers =\> ":9091"
security_protocol =\> ""
ssl_key_password =\> ""
ssl_keystore_password =\> ""
ssl_truststore_password =\> ""
ssl_keystore_location =\> "/tmp"
ssl_truststore_location =\> "/tmp"
topic_id =\> "test"
ssl_endpoint_identification_algorithm =\> ""
}
stdout {}
}
```

I want to use multiple KafKas to connect successfully without being affected by a single connection failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the output isolator pattern to prevent Logstash from becoming blocked if one of multiple outputs experiences a temporary failure. Logstash, by default, is blocked when any single output is down. This behavior is important in guaranteeing at-least-once delivery of data.

example code:

```
# config/pipelines.yml
- pipeline.id: intake
  config.string: |
    input { beats { port => 5044 } }
    output { pipeline { send_to => [es, http] } }
- pipeline.id: buffered-es
  queue.type: persisted
  config.string: |
    input { pipeline { address => es } }
    output { elasticsearch { } }
- pipeline.id: buffered-http
  queue.type: persisted
  config.string: |
    input { pipeline { address => http } }
    output { http { } }
```

I hope this help you

Comment: Thank you for your help. It has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

first, ensure that kafka brokers service port is up and running.
in your case 9091 as you mention in your request.
telnet kafka_server1 9091
telnet kafka_server2 9091
telnet kafka_server3 9091
if not then restart kafka service

then set all your brokers in your logstash output following the next format
The format is host1:port1,host2:port2, and the list can be a subset of brokers or a VIP pointing to a subset of brokers.

```
input {
  # Your input configuration, e.g., file, beats, etc.
}

filter {
  # Your filter configuration, if needed
}

output {
  kafka {
    #### List of Kafka bootstrap servers
    bootstrap_servers => "kafka_server1:9091,kafka_server2:9091,kafka_server3:9091"

    ####  Kafka topic to which Logstash will send messages
    topic_id => "your_kafka_topic"

    ####  Optional settings (you may need to adjust based on your Kafka setup)
    codec => "json"
    acks => "all"
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer, but what I mean is if I have multiple different outputs, such as kafka and syslog or txt files. If one Kafka connection on my end fails, all other outputs will not work. What is the reason for this?

Comment: In that case you must use output isolator pattern.